Removing empty page before acronyms list in openright memoir class
I am writing my thesis using the memoir class with the following options:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

I am looking to print the acronyms list without a blank page coming from the openright rule. Indeed, the acronyms list is treated by memoir as a "Chapter" and \chapter should start on left hand pages due to the openright rule. I have looked extensively on Stack Exchange and found that this question should answer mine. Many other questions suggest using \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage. However, in my case it does not seem to work... The only thing that seems to work is using \let\clearpage\relax. However, the title of the list of acronyms has a strange indent that I am not able to remove. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Here is my main document (so that you have a MWE):
\documentclass[12pt, 
a4paper, 
twoside, 
openright, 
oldfontcommands]{memoir}
% In the memoir class there is no identation as standard of the paragraphs.
% \let\footruleskip\undefined % undefine footruleskip
\input{Preamble} % load the options 
\input{MyMathSymbols} % load the math symbols
\input{Chapters/Acronyms} % Input them before begin document

% Memoire class options -------------------------
% Setting caption and subcaption styles from the caption and subcaption packages.
\captionsetup{font=scriptsize}  % Sets the font size for main captions
\captionsetup[sub]{font=tiny}  % Sets the font size for all subcaptions
% \captionsetup{justification=centering}

% Memoir class options: Control the numbering of sections
\settocdepth{subsection}
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}

% To leave empty space at the bottom of the page when not enough text to fill the page.
\raggedbottom
% Memoire class options -------------------------


% Bibtex ------------------------------------
\addbibresource{thesis_bib_all.bib} % load the Bib file

% Document ------------------------------
\begin{document}
\frontmatter 

% Page style control: From here until you re-set it.
\pagestyle{empty}

% Title page ----------------------------------
\include{Titlepage}

% Thanks ---------------------------------------
\include{Chapters/Thanks}

% Abstract --------------------------------------------
\pagestyle{plain} % Start the plain style from here, do not redefine it in fancyhdr.
\include{Chapters/Abstract}
% % \addcontentsline{toc}{Chapter}{Abstract}

% % Aknowledgement ------------------------------------
% \include{Chapters/Acknowlegement}
% % \addcontentsline{toc}{Chapter}{Acknowledgements}

% Table of contents -----------------------------
\hypersetup{linkcolor=black} % temporarily chnage it to black
\tableofcontents* 
\newpage

% List of figures -----------------------------
\listoffigures* 
\newpage

% List of tables --------------------------------
\listoftables*
% \thispagestyle{empty}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue} % reset it to blue


% List of acronyms --------------------------------
% \vspace{-10cm}
{
\let\clearpage\relax % temporarily relax the definition of clearpage inside these brackets. So that this list does not start on the right.
\glsaddall % Command ensures that all defined acronyms are added to the glossary, even if they haven't been used in the text. 
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title=List of Acronyms, nonumberlist]  % Print the list of acronyms without hyperlinks
}
% \clearpage % The \clearpage command guarantees that any content that follows will start on a fresh new page, adhering to the openright convention of starting chapters on right-hand pages

\mainmatter
\OnehalfSpacing  % Set line spacing to 1.5 for the main content with memoir class, starting at this step

% Page style control: From here until you re-set it.
\pagestyle{fancy}

%-- Introduction
% Memoir: \chapter[<ToC entry>][<header entry>]{<chapter title>}
\chapter[Introduction][Introduction]{Introduction}
\label{Chap: intro}
\input{Chapters/Introduction}
\clearpage % The \clearpage command guarantees that any content that follows will start on a fresh new page, adhering to the openright convention of starting chapters on right-hand pages

% Citation 1 -----------------------
% \pagestyle{empty}
% \include{Chapters/Citation1}
% \clearpage

% Chapter 1 ------------------------
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chapter[Chapter 1][Chapter 1]{\Large Chapter 1}
\label{Chap: thesis1}
\input{Chapters/Chapter1}
\clearpage

% Citation 2 -----------------------
% \pagestyle{empty}
% \include{Chapters/Citation2}
% \clearpage

% Chapter 2 ------------------------
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chapter[Chapter 2][Chapter 2]{\Large Chapter 2}
\label{Chap: thesis2}
\input{Chapters/Chapter2}
\clearpage

% Citation 3 -----------------------
% \pagestyle{empty}
% \include{Chapters/Citation3}
% \clearpage

% Chapter 3 ------------------------
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chapter[Chapter 3][Chapter 3]{\Large Chapter 3}
\label{Chap: thesis3}
\input{Chapters/Chapter3}
\clearpage

% Conclusion------------------------
\chapter[Conclusion][Conclusion]{Conclusion}
\label{Chap: conclusion}
\input{Chapters/Conclusion}

\backmatter 

%%% Bibliography --------------------------------------
% Print a single bibliography for the entire document at the end.
\SingleSpacing % re set single spacing at this stage
\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt] % Redefine it for the reference list
\printbibliography % 

% \bibliography{thesis_bib_all.bib}  % This command prints the Reference list at this point in the code.


\end{document}


\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage would break openright and twoside options.  \let\clearpage\clearpage would break latex entirely.

please provide a small example that shows the problem, you have posted a lot of code but it does not show anything or help anyone answer as only you can run it as it uses many files not provided.

Dear David, thank you very much for your comment and suggestions. I think I may have a solution after all. I have never answered my questions yet on Stack... but I think that this time the solution I found may be beneficial to people facing a similar issue. Do not hesitate to give me your opinion :)

your answer looks fine to me although I don't know memoir that well. the code in the first comment should have said . \let\clearpage\relax will break latex of course.

In my case, adding \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage did not work, it did not break the openright and twoside, as my acronym list was printed on a "right page" hence the undesired blank page before its appearance. While \let\clearpage\relax (without the dot) "succeeded" but in a strange way (the title of the Acronym list has a strange indentation). I guess it came from the breaking you pointed out. Thanks for your help !

don't even try \let\clearpage\relax  if you get any output at all it is by luck, it could easily result in latex not terminating at all and needing to be stopped by killing the process.

\documentclass{article} \let\clearpage\relax \begin{document} hello world \end{document}

I found a solution by looking at the memoir manual. Independently of what you stated in the global options, you can subsequently manually control the operight rule via these commands:
\openright \openleft \openany

Applied to my sample this gives:
% List of acronyms --------------------------------
\openany % temporarily set to any
\glsaddall % Command ensures that all defined acronyms are added to the glossary, even if they haven't been used in the text. 
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title=List of Acronyms, nonumberlist]  % Print the list of acronyms without hyperlinks

% List of mathematical notations --------------------------------
\printnomenclature
\openright % reset to right for the rest of the document

It is important to note that for memoir also the book class inspired solutions like: \makeatletter\@openrightfalse\makeatother do not work unfortunately.
